# Find the coordinate of the vertex of a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

**Question:** In the trapezoid $ABCD, A(4,5), B(1,1), C(-1,4), \overleftrightarrow{AB}\parallel\overleftrightarrow{CD},\overline{CD}=2$, find the coordinate of $D$.

**My attempt:**

because $\overleftrightarrow{AB}\parallel\overleftrightarrow{CD}$, therefore they have the same slope, we get $$m_{\overleftrightarrow{CD}}=\frac{4}{3}$$
By using the point-slope formula, we get the linear equation of $\overleftrightarrow{CD}$ is $$L_{\overleftrightarrow{CD}}:y-4=\frac{4}{3}(x+1)$$
which is  $$L_{\overleftrightarrow{CD}}:4x-3y=-16$$
because $D$ is on $L_{\overleftrightarrow{CD}}$, therefore we can assume the coordinate of $D$ is $$D(t, \frac{4t+16}{3})$$
by using $\overline{CD}=2$, sqare both sides we get $$(t+1)^2+(\frac{4t+16}{3}-4)^2=4$$
after simplifying and factoring we get
$$(5t-1)(5t+11)=0$$
we get $t=\frac{1}{5}$ or $-\frac{11}{5}$, therefore the coordinate of $D$ is
$$(\frac{1}{5}, \frac{28}{5})\text{or}(-\frac{11}{5}, \frac{12}{5})$$

But there's only one answer $(\frac{1}{5}, \frac{28}{5})$, why? $D$ can be above $C$ or below it, can't it?

Comment: As the answer geometrically shows, that $D$ has to be the right of $C$. Algebraically, this means that the $x$ coordinate of $D$ is more positive than $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the graph below, because the other point $D'$ does not make it trapezoid, but a broken line.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Note: The ordering is important: $ABCD$ and $ABDC$ are different figures.